# toThrow() inside do-while loop not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I am attempting to add a unit-test for a decode function that has a do-while loop, my test expects the function to throw an error but the toThrow() function does not realize an error has been thrown, the test fails (due to the function itself throwing an error).

Here is the decode function:

```js
readVarLong() {
let currentByte
let result = Long.fromInt(0)
let i = 0

do {
  currentByte = this.buffer[this.offset++]
  result = result.add(Long.fromInt(currentByte & OTHER_BITS).shiftLeft(i))
  i += 7
  if (i > 63) {
    throw new KafkaJSInvalidLongError('Invalid Long, must contain 9 bytes or less')
  }
} while (currentByte >= MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT)

return Decoder.decodeZigZag64(result)
```

}

Here is the test (which is placed in a describe, alongside many other tests in the original file):

```
const decode64 = buffer => new Decoder(buffer).readVarLong()
const B = (...args) => Buffer.from(args)
expect(() =>
        decode64(B(0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x01))
).toThrow()
```

The error is an extension of KafkaJSNonRetriableError which I implemented:

```
class KafkaJSInvalidLongError extends KafkaJSNonRetriableError {
   constructor() {
      super(...arguments)
      this.name = 'KafkaJSNonRetriableError'
   }
}
```

When running 'yarn jest' I end up receiving this error:

```
KafkaJSNonRetriableError: Invalid Long, must contain 9 bytes or less

      232 |       i += 7
      233 |       if (i > 63) {
    > 234 |         throw new KafkaJSInvalidLongError('Invalid Long, must contain 9 bytes or less')
          |               ^
      235 |       }
      236 |     } while (currentByte >= MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT)
      237 |
```

This is the repository that contains the code I am trying to modify. The code you see in the example I gave above is not present in the original repository.
https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs

Relevant files are:

[decoder.js](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/master/src/protocol/decoder.js)
[encoder.spec.js](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/master/src/protocol/encoder.spec.js)

I also opened an issue on Jest's github repo: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11249

Am I using the .toThrow() wrong? or I found an actual bug?

Edit:
Putting it outside of the do-while does seem to work, but I don't want to re-code this function just so it works without do-while seems like a problem with Jest.

Comment: May I ask the source of `KafkaJSInvalidLongError`? It doesn't exist in KafkaJS. Is that a custom EventEmitter?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I added it to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Another test was failing instead, not the one I expected to throw an error.